# Minha declaração de struct está errada?

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, funções, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
fun1(int ptr,int data)
{
    data.ano=1990;
    data.mes=5;
    data.dia=15;
    ptr->nome="Bigown";
    ptr->cpf="040502016";
}

int main ()
{
typedef struct {
    int ano;
    int mes;
    int dia;
} Data;
struct pessoa {
    char nome[20];
    char [12];
    Data data_nasc;
} x,*ptr;
    func1(*ptr,data);
    printf ("Data : %d/%d/%d \nPessoa:%s\nCPF:%s ",data.dia,data.mes,data.dia,ptr->nome,ptr->cpf);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: especifique melhor sua pergunta

Comment: Eu coloquei a *tag* C++ porque em pergunta anterior mostrou que está desenvolvendo em um compilador C++, e como a resposta serve também para quem está procurando por C++, acho que ajuda a pergunta ser achada por outras pessoas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma boa prática definir os tipos separados das `structs`. Primeiro definimos os tipos e depois definimos as `structs`. Isso evita dependências circulares e deixa o código mais legível.

Essa técnica se chama `Forward Delaration`. A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) possui um artigo falando mais sobre tal técnica.

Segue mais uma solução para o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* Forward Declarations */
typedef struct data_s data_t;
typedef struct pessoa_s pessoa_t;


struct data_s
{
    int ano;
    int mes;
    int dia;
};


struct pessoa_s
{
    char nome[20];
    char cpf[12];
    data_t data_nasc;
};


pessoa_t * obter_pessoa( void )
{
    pessoa_t * p = malloc(sizeof(pessoa_t));

    strcpy(p->nome, "Maniero");
    strcpy(p->cpf, "040502016");
    p->data_nasc.ano = 1990;
    p->data_nasc.mes = 5;
    p->data_nasc.dia = 15;

    return p;
}


void exibir_pessoa( pessoa_t * p )
{
    printf("Data: %d/%d/%d\n", p->data_nasc.dia, p->data_nasc.mes, p->data_nasc.ano );
    printf("Pessoa: %s\n", p->nome );
    printf("CPF: %s\n", p->cpf);
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    pessoa_t * p = obter_pessoa();

    exibir_pessoa(p);

    free(p);

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: ajudo demais que codigo bonito de se ler, valeu

Answer (score 4):

O código tem vários erros que vou listar. Para aprender precisa entender o que está fazendo. Tem que ler os erros do compilador, interpretá-los, procurar por eles e achar uma solução. É assim que todos os programadores fazem. Claro que o ideal é estudar profundamente a linguagem, fazer o código com cuidado e evitar os erros. Nem sempre é possível, claro, mas se o código for feito sabendo do que se trata, com cuidado, de forma organizada, o compilador vai dando os erros e pode-se consertar pelo menos o básico.

Precisa aprender com os erros e não voltar cometê-los em códigos subsequentes, como o ocorreu aqui.

Havia vários erros de sintaxe bem básicos, erros como nome na declaração de função ou membro de estrutura e depois uso de outro nome na chamada e atribuição. Havia erro até de membro sem nome (`cpf`).

O código segue pouca ou nenhum estrutura coerente e plausível. Tem até variáveis não usadas.

A primeira mudança que fiz foi separar a estrutura de dados do algoritmo. Deixei as estruturas fora da função para serem usadas em todo o código. Também criei tipos com `typedef` para facilitar o trabalho depois. É assim que se costuma fazer em código real. Note que preferi usar nomes em maiúsculo para os tipos. Pura convenção para facilitar a leitura depois.

Criei uma variável para guardar os dados de uma pessoa e aloquei a memória, conforme parece ser a intenção (não precisaria usar ponteiro e [alocar memória no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), esta é apenas uma das opções, a segui, talvez seja um requisito do exercício).

Passei esta variável para a função de forma simples. Ela já é um ponteiro. Não precisa criar e passar uma variável `data` porque o uso da data está dentro da pessoa, não é algo independente. Até poderia, mas desnecessário. Mas se vai passar, então a variável teria que ser criada antes, não pode passar o que não existe.

Na função que vai atribuir os dados tem erro porque falta o tipo de retorno (no caso por não ter um retorno seria `void`). Além de precisar só de um parâmetro, ele deveria ser do tipo `Pessoa` e não `int`. Não pode chutar coisas. Note que não foi preciso usar `struct` antes de `Pessoa`, porque agora ela foi declarada como um tipo de dado.

Dentro da função só é atribuído os dados à estrutura. O primeiro erro é que a data está sendo tratada de forma independente. Como a data faz parte da estrutura da pessoa, tem que acessar cada um dos seus membros através da variável `pessoa` (note que preferi usar um nome mais significativo do que é a variável de fato). Então eu acesso a variável `pessoa`, aí o membro `data_nasc` (acertei o nome) e dentro dele acessei os seus membros `dia`, `mes` e `ano`. Só precisei usar o operador `.` ao invés de `->` porque neste caso estou acessando o dado de forma direta e não através de um ponteiro.

Os outros dois dados estão errados porque em C uma *string* não pode ser atribuída diretamente para uma variável, é preciso copiar seus caracteres com a função [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

Por fim, arrumei o `printf()` que tinha pequenos problemas de sintaxe nos argumentos e formatação.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int ano;
    int mes;
    int dia;
} Data;
typedef struct {
    char nome[20];
    char cpf[12];
    Data data_nasc;
} Pessoa;
void func1(Pessoa *pessoa) {
    strcpy(pessoa->nome, "Maniero");
    strcpy(pessoa->cpf, "040502016");
    pessoa->data_nasc.ano = 1990;
    pessoa->data_nasc.mes = 5;
    pessoa->data_nasc.dia = 15;
}
int main() {
    Pessoa *pessoa = malloc(sizeof(Pessoa));
    func1(pessoa);
    printf("Data: %d/%d/%d\nPessoa: %s\nCPF: %s ", pessoa->data_nasc.dia, pessoa->data_nasc.mes, pessoa->data_nasc.ano, pessoa->nome, pessoa->cpf);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/fork/eV9lwH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ekjogcxt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Example.c).

Obviamente que se a data for algo meramente descritiva e não precisa usar para mais nada, pode usá-la apenas como se fosse uma *string*, assim como fez com CPF.

Comment: Sim estou meio perdido nessa mare, e muita coisa em c que eu preciso aprender , gastarei meu final de semana estudando e revisando o que voce me ensino bigown, ainda falta uma pequena parte do exercicio. Esse printf deveria ser invocado de uma função e nao na main, eu vou tentar resolver essa parte do exercicio, ja que voce me deu o caminho, me esforçarei para terminar. Obrigado

Comment: O ideal é fazer perguntas com problemas mais delimitados, normalmente sua pergunta até seria fechada com tantos problemas que tem. Não tem problema fazer várias perguntas, problema é não ter um problema específico em cada uma delas. Pode perguntar sobre erro, sobre conceito que não entendeu, qualquer coisa, desde que seja de programação, seja específico, a pergunta seja feita de forma clara e não peça opiniões, precisa ser algo objetivo.

Comment: bigown eu consegui realizar a ultima etapa que e imprimir usando a função os valores da estrutura . Eu entendi tudo o que voce me mostro ate agora e vou continuar programando para ter fixação no conteudo ensinado, agradeço demais amigo.